# First() & Single() returns 1 element but need all elements

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to understand a small piece of code, i don't usually use LINQ but i think i am better to get stuck in and learn the syntax, the code is:

```
            var inputHtml = browser
                .Document
                .GetElementsByTagName("input")
                .Cast<HtmlElement>()
                .Single()
                .OuterHtml;

            var elementHtmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            elementHtmlDoc.LoadHtml(inputHtml);

            var attributesDictionary = elementHtmlDoc
                .DocumentNode
                .ChildNodes
                .First()
                .Attributes
                .ToDictionary(attr => attr.Name, attr => attr.Value);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in attributesDictionary)
            {
                Helpers.ReturnMessage(entry.Value + " -> " + entry.Key);
            }
```

Currently here `.Single()` and also `.First()` only returns 1 element, but in my example there is more than 1 element, is there a way to store all elements? `browser` is the html source code of a webbrowser control, i'm trying to store all **input** tags to the dictionary. from doing some reading i cannot see the correct way to do this with LINQ.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: instead of `Single().OuterHtml` use `Select(i => i.OuterHtml).ToList()` which should leave you with a list of `OuterHtml` for all the input elements.

Comment: Thank you Tobias this has given me another way too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just eliminate the `.First()` or the `.Single()`. Each of those returns one item from a collection (specifically an `IEnumerable`)

Without the `.First()`, `attributesDictionary` should be an IEnumerable and the `foreach` should iterate through the items.

Both `.First()` and `.Single()` are designed to convert an IEnumerable (which is a collection-type class) into a single instance, but `.Single()` should throw an exception if the IEnumerable contains more than one instance. It sounds like you're expecting `inputHtml` to have more than one member, but if it doesn't throw an exception when including the `.Single()`, I don't think that's the case.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Jeff! appreciated.